# Accessing temporary changes to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

An old college of mine have spend a lot of time implementing a database in Microsoft SQL Server, where he updates it with a VBA macro. The database update takes 6 minutes and is performed with multiple updates of each observation. This makes the observations in an invalid state during the update.

My question is there a quick fix make others able to query a database while he updates? And is this both possible if he wants to read from the intermediate state and if he makes only write only changes?

I know it is not pretty and we are going to exchange the database latter. So do not answer: "move away from VBA".

Comment: You need to identify where the low performance is coming from- is vba slow? Is the update query poorly optimized and taking too long to run?  There’s virtually nothing we can do to answer your question in its current state - you’ve already said it would be inappropriate to query the db during an update so it’s not like recommending a no-locks scenario would help (if it’s even row locking that causes the slowness)

Comment: Those "multiple updates" should be done in a single transaction, then the database won't be in an invalid state during the update process

Comment: What @horse says in conjunction with snapshot isolation should do what you need

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solve it by doing these:

1. create index on the table (if it doesn't already have one)
2. alter the index and set ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = off and ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = on
3. query the table by "readpast" to avoid uncommitted records without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of on the limited amount of info posted, would be to copy the database before it is updated, and allow programs that still need read only access to query the copy while the main one is being updated